# React and Redux: Uncaught Error: A state mutation was detected between dispatches

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am using 'controlled' components (using `setState()` within the component) and getting this error intermittently when attempting to save the form data.  The `UserForm` `onSave` calls back to the `saveUser` method in the component code below.

I've looked at the Redux docs on this and can't quite get my head around where I'm modifying the state to cause the error in the title, which is specifically: `Uncaught Error: A state mutation was detected between dispatches, in the path 'users.2'. This may cause incorrect behavior.`

As far as I can tell, only local modifications are being made, and the reducer is returning a copy of the global state with my changes added.  I must be missing something, but what?

Here's the component code:

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import * as userActions from '../../actions/userActions';
import UserForm from './UserForm';


export class ManageUserPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {
      user:  Object.assign({}, this.props.user),
      errors:  {},
      saving:  false
    };
    this.updateUserState = this.updateUserState.bind(this);
    this.saveUser = this.saveUser.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.user.id != nextProps.user.id) {
      this.setState(
        {
          user:  Object.assign({}, nextProps.user)
        }
      );
    }
  }

  updateUserState(event) {
    const field = event.target.name;
    let user = Object.assign({}, this.state.user);
    user[field] = event.target.value;
    return this.setState({user: user});
  }

  userFormIsValid() {
    let formIsValid = true;
    let errors = {};

    if (this.state.user.firstName.length < 3) {
      errors.firstName = 'Name must be at least 3 characters.';
      formIsValid = false;
    }
    this.setState({errors: errors});
    return formIsValid;
  }


  saveUser(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!this.userFormIsValid()) {
      return;
    }
    this.setState({saving: true});
    this.props.actions
      .saveUser(this.state.user)
      .then(() => this.redirect())
      .catch((error) => {
        this.setState({saving: false});
      });
  }

  redirect() {
    this.setState({saving: false});
    this.context.router.push('/users');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <UserForm
        onChange={this.updateUserState}
        onSave={this.saveUser}
        errors={this.state.errors}
        user={this.state.user}
        saving={this.state.saving}/>
    );
  }
}

ManageUserPage.propTypes = {
  user:  PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  actions: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

ManageUserPage.contextTypes = {
  router: PropTypes.object
};


function getUserById(users, userId) {
  const user = users.find(u => u.id === userId);
  return user || null;
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  let user = {
    id:        '',
    firstName: '',
    lastName:  ''
  };

  const userId = ownProps.params.id;

  if (state.users.length && userId) {
    user = getUserById(state.users, userId);
  }


  return {
    user:  user
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(userActions, dispatch)
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ManageUserPage);
```

Here's the reducer:

```
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';
import initialState from './initialState';


export default(state = initialState.users, action) =>
{
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.CREATE_USER_SUCCESS:
      return [
        // grab our state, then add our new user in
        ...state,
        Object.assign({}, action.user)
      ];

    case types.UPDATE_USER_SUCCESS:
      return [
        // filter out THIS user from our copy of the state, then add our updated user in
        ...state.filter(user => user.id !== action.user.id),
        Object.assign({}, action.user)
      ];

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Here are the actions:

```
import * as types from './actionTypes';
import userApi from '../api/mockUserApi';
import {beginAjaxCall, ajaxCallError} from './ajaxStatusActions';


export function createUserSuccess(user) {
  return {type: types.CREATE_USER_SUCCESS, user};
}

export function updateUserSuccess(user) {
  return {type: types.UPDATE_USER_SUCCESS, user};
}

export function saveUser(user) {
  return function (dispatch, getState) {
    dispatch(beginAjaxCall());
    return userApi.saveUser(user)
      .then(savedUser => {
        user.id
          ? dispatch(updateUserSuccess(savedUser))
          : dispatch(createUserSuccess(savedUser));
      }).catch(error => {
        dispatch(ajaxCallError(error));
        throw(error);
      });
  };
}
```

Here's the mock API layer:

```
import delay from './delay';

const users = [
  {
    id: 'john-smith',
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Smith'
  }
];

const generateId = (user) => {
  return user.firstName.toLowerCase() + '-' + user.lastName.toLowerCase();
};

class UserApi {
  static saveUser(user) {
    user = Object.assign({}, user); 
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const minUserNameLength = 3;
        if (user.firstName.length < minUserNameLength) {
          reject(`First Name must be at least ${minUserNameLength} characters.`);
        }

        if (user.lastName.length < minUserNameLength) {
          reject(`Last Name must be at least ${minUserNameLength} characters.`);
        }

        if (user.id) {
          const existingUserIndex = users.findIndex(u => u.id == u.id);
          users.splice(existingUserIndex, 1, user);
        } else {
          user.id = generateId(user);
          users.push(user);
        }
        resolve(user);
      }, delay);
    });
  }
}

export default UserApi;
```

Comment: in mapStateToProps, why are you returning users and user?

Comment: @HusseinAlkaf you're right, that's not needed.  I had reused this component from another.  It doesn't affect the error, of course, but edited.  Thanks!

Comment: For future seekers: In my case this error occurred when I tried to mutate a value taken from state.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

@DDS pointed me in the right direction (thanks!) in that it was mutation elsewhere that was causing the problem.

`ManageUserPage` is the top-level component in the DOM, but a different component on another route called `UsersPage`, was mutating state in its render method.

Initially the render method looked like this:

```
render() {
    const users = this.props.users.sort(alphaSort);
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Users</h1>
        <input type="submit"
               value="Add User"
               className="btn btn-primary"
               onClick={this.redirectToAddUserPage}/>
        <UserList
          users={users}/>
      </div>
    );
}
```

I changed the `users` assignment to the following and the issue was resolved:

```
const users = [...this.props.users].sort(alphaSort);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... 9Hrs of long debugging and i dint know this was the issue. Thanks again mate :)

Comment: The key is cloning the array when reading from the Redux selector like `[...originalValues]`

Comment: Thank you for this! Saved me hours of head-scratching. The annoying part is I learned about array cloning before and remember the teacher saying specifically that this is a common problem. But of course I didn't note it down anywhere and completely forgot it was a thing. God bless SO.

Answer (score 11):

The problem isn't in this component or the reducer. It's probably in the parent component, where you're probably assigning `users[ix] = savedUser` somewhere, and the users array is ultimately the same array as the one in the state.

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue and none of above approaches worked. Upon debouncing the update of Redux store, it got resolved:

I use lodash for debounce, but you can create your own utility function

instead of

```js
dispatch(updateUserSuccess(savedUser))
```

This one worked:

```js
import * as _ from 'lodash'

_.debounce(dispatch(updateUserSuccess(savedUser)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem with state mutations by following any of the update patterns suggested on [redux official docs](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns)

I prefer using `createReducer` in reducer which uses [immer.produce](https://github.com/immerjs/immer#api) behind the scenes:

```
import { createReducer } from 'redux-starter-kit'

const initialState = {
  first: {
    second: {
      id1: { fourth: 'a' },
      id2: { fourth: 'b' }
    }
  }
}

const reducer = createReducer(initialState, {
  UPDATE_ITEM: (state, action) => {
    state.first.second[action.someId].fourth = action.someValue
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Mutable operations include push, pop, splice, shift, unshift, reverse and sort. But 'the state' is immutable, so you either need to find replacable functions for them (e.g., using 'concat()' instead of 'push()'), or use them on a copy from the spread array, e.g.:

```
const users = [...this.props.users].sort(alphaSort)
```

(where you copy the users by [...arr],so the original 'users-state' has not being mutated)