# Error: Invariant failed: A state mutation was detected between dispatches in next js

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js

When I try to change the state from the front-end, the error shows...

***Error: Invariant failed: A state mutation was detected between dispatches, in the path 'products.productAttributes.0.attribute'.  This may cause incorrect behavior. (https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#do-not-mutate-state)***

**My Reducer  :**

```
    import {
  GET_PRODUCTS_BY_QUERY,
  GET_PRODUCT_BY_ID,
  GET_PRODUCTS,
  PRODUCT_DATA_ON_PROGRESS,
  PRODUCT_DATA_SUBMIT_PROGRESS,
  OPEN_PRODUCT_SIDEBAR,
  BIND_PRODUCT_BASIC_INFO,
  BIND_PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTES,
} from '../action-types';
import { ProductBasicInfoModal, attributes } from '../model';

const initialState = {
  dataProgress: false,
  submitProductDataProgress: false,
  openProductSidebar: false,
  products: [],
  productAttributes: attributes,
  product: ProductBasicInfoModal,
  total: 1,
  queryParams: {},
  queryObj: {},
};

const productReducers = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_PRODUCTS_BY_QUERY:
      return {
        ...state,
        products: action.products,
        total: action.total,
        queryParams: action.queryParams,
        queryObj: action.queryObj,
      };

    case GET_PRODUCT_BY_ID:
      return {
        ...state,
        product: action.product,
      };
    case BIND_PRODUCT_BASIC_INFO:
      return {
        ...state,
        product: action.product,
      };
    case BIND_PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTES:
      return {
        ...state,
        productAttributes: action.attributes,
      };
    case PRODUCT_DATA_ON_PROGRESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        dataProgress: action.dataProgress,
      };

    case PRODUCT_DATA_SUBMIT_PROGRESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        submitProductDataProgress: action.submitProductDataProgress,
      };
    case OPEN_PRODUCT_SIDEBAR:
      return {
        ...state,
        openProductSidebar: action.openProductSidebar,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default productReducers;
```

**Then My Action:**

```
export const bindProductAttributes = (data) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: BIND_PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTES,
    attributes: data,
  });
};
```

***Here is my Component Function:***

**

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { product, productAttributes } = useSelector(
    ({ products }) => products
  );
  const handleDropdownOChange = (data, e, rowId) => {
    const { name } = e;
    const attributes = [...productAttributes].map((att) => {
      if (att.id === rowId) {
        att[name] = data;
      }
      return att;
    });
    dispatch(bindProductAttributes(attributes));
  };
```

**

***I faced the problem when the action **handleDropdownOChange** is fired!***

Please Help me !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React and Redux: Uncaught Error: A state mutation was detected between dispatches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41051302/react-and-redux-uncaught-error-a-state-mutation-was-detected-between-dispatche)

Comment: This is the [second question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75669570/how-to-fix-a-state-mutation-was-detected-between-dispatches) tonight regarding redux state mutations. Both using old redux code instead of current `reduxjs/toolkit` code. Chances are it's that somewhere in the UI some redux state has been selected and the UI is mutating it. Try to simplify/narrow the UI to see what exactly triggers the error.

Comment: Same Question but answer will not same

Comment: The post I linked to doesn't have an answer, but the suggestion is the same that likely somewhere in the UI it is mutating some selected redux state.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is most likely the line `att[name] = data;`.  This *mutates* `att`, and that variable is an object that originally came from the Redux store.  Don't do that :)

The *best* answer here is to instead dispatch an action that might contain the row ID and the data, and let the *reducer* take care of handling the update:

- https://redux.js.org/style-guide/#put-as-much-logic-as-possible-in-reducers
- https://redux.js.org/style-guide/#reducers-should-own-the-state-shape

You should also use Redux Toolkit's `createSlice` to write that reducer.

Those pieces together will make it much simpler to manage the update, *and* eliminate the accidental mutation problem.